# AWS EC2 instance Rails 4 error on production but not on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am struggling to trouble shoot my app.  I am new to AWS EC2 and come from Heroku.  Generally I would use my "heroku logs --tail" console command to see why my app is erroring but on AWS I do not have that luxury (or at least know how).

To enter my production environment in the command line I...

...go to the folder where my example.pem is

...type ssh -i example.pem ubuntu@55.555.55.555

...type cd /etc/

...type cd /etc/projects/myapp

and from there I can

..."git pull origin master" to do my github pulls

..."sudo service apache2 reload" to restart my server after a change

...run "rails s" to see the logs on the local server.

The error does not happen when on "rails s" 55.555.55.555:3000 it only errors on live production 55.555.55.555.

How can I troubleshoot or at least see the production logs?

Comment: do you see anything in production log? `cd /etc/projects/myapp` then `tail -f log/production.log`?

Comment: @Surya thank you.  using tail -f log/production was what I was looking for.  Please post as answer and I will mark correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use(inside Rails app directory):

`tail -f log/production.log`